# Incorrect operation of the sort () method on Node v.8.1.3?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

There is an array at the input

```
['1:nnn','1:vvv','2:zzz','1:yy','1:cc','2:xx','2:uu','2:tt','2:qq','2:aa','1:ff','1:ll','1:pp']
```

You must specify a comparator in the sort () method so that the array is sorted according to the following principles:

1) Keep the original sorting by the length of the elements (do not interchange elements of different lengths, for example, elements 1: nnn and 1: yy)

2) If the elements are the same length, then compare the first character of each element, first the elements with the prefix 1 must go, then the elements with the prefix 2.

I tried to write the following code, but I can’t understand why it does not work as I would like on Node v.8.1.3? The incorrect result that I get looks like this:

```
['2:uu','1:nnn','1:ll','1:yy','1:cc','2:xx','1:ff','2:tt','2:qq','2:aa','1:vvv','2:zzz','1:pp']
```

If I run the code in a browser or in stackoverflow, then I get the expected result:

```
["1:nnn","1:vvv","2:zzz","1:yy","1:cc","1:ff","1:ll","1:pp","2:xx","2:uu","2:tt","2:qq","2:aa"]
```

What could be the problem and what am I doing wrong?

```js
let output=['1:nnn','1:vvv','2:zzz','1:yy','1:cc','2:xx','2:uu','2:tt','2:qq','2:aa','1:ff','1:ll','1:pp']

output.sort((a,b) => {
  if(a.length===b.length) {
     if ((+a.slice(0,1))<(+b.slice(0,1))) return -1 
     else return 1
  } else return 0
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: See if this helps - https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort
Your browser is probably using a newer version of v8 than that of nodejs v8.1.3, potentially contributing to the difference in results.

Can you provide the v8 version of your browser? Will help confirm this shaky theory :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a symetrically sorting and not a boolean value for only returning one or two values.

[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) expects three values, depending of the wanted and given order, but your result misses one value, which might be important, depending on the sort algorithm of the implementation.

Instead, you could return the delta of the values and get a perfect sorted result, independent of the implementation.

```js
let output=['1:nnn','1:vvv','2:zzz','1:yy','1:cc','2:xx','2:uu','2:tt','2:qq','2:aa','1:ff','1:ll','1:pp']

output.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length || a.split(':', 1) - b.split(':', 1));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I have never seen limit used in a split before

Comment: I assume it is identical to `a.split(':')[0]` ?

Comment: not really, the split with limit returns still an array, but with one element. the minus operator converts the array first to a string (for joining the array) and then to a number.